# Protobuf change field wire type

Tags: protocol-buffers

I did't find any useful answer to this question:
If I have a protobuf definition:

```
message Mother{
  Person child = 1;
}
message Person{
  string name = 1;
}
message Baby{
  string name = 1;
}
```

is it safe (backward compatible) for me to change Mother to:

```
message Mother{
  Baby child = 1;
}
```

since message Person and Baby has exact the same layout and inner wire types?

The reason for asking is I would like to migrate the field definition to another proto file and import it (for better structuring), which is roughly the same problem as described above.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Google Protobuf Documentation on DO's & DON'Ts](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/dos-donts/#change-type), changing the field type is generally considered unsafe—even if the field numbers are consistent. This could introduce compatibility issues, especially when different implementations of Protobuf across various languages are involved.

#### Experimental Test

I conducted an experiment using Python to investigate the implications of changing field types. Below is the Python code:

```py
# First run: Uncomment this block to write a serialized message using the old schema
# from generated.some_pb2 import Mother, Person, Baby
# mother_old = Mother(child=Person(name="Amit"))
# with open('./test_schema.pb', 'wb') as file:
#     file.write(mother_old.SerializeToString())

# Second run: Uncomment this block to read the serialized message using the new schema
# from generated2.some_pb2 import Mother, Baby, Person
# with open('./test_schema.pb', 'rb') as file:
#     content = file.read()
#     mother_new = Mother.FromString(content)
#     print(mother_new)
```

From this test, I found that the new schema was able to correctly deserialize messages serialized with the old schema. However, this is based on a limited test and shouldn't be considered universally safe.

#### Caveats and Recommendations

Despite the test results, changing field types is risky and could lead to problems depending on how you intend to use "older" compiled Protobuf files against "newer" versions. I would strongly advise against making this change without good comprehensive testing.

If you're using multiple languages in your system, I haven't yet tested the compatibility there, so proceed with caution.

#### Alternatively

As an alternative, consider implementing **versioning** to manage schema changes safely:

- Add package to your `.proto` files with a version component at the end such as: `my_package.v1` (can add alpha/beta suffix)
- Nest your copy of the old file in new `/v2` folder and add a package corresponding to the new version path

Or introducing new field with the new type and mark the old field as deprecated

```
Person child = 1 [deperecated = true];
Baby new_child = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

In practice you are not changing the wire type or even field type here - **you are changing the message name**.

Message and field names are not encoded in protobuf, so changing them is safe for compatibility of the serialized data.

Comment: it actually has a type change: from type Person to Baby, it is just that Person and Baby have exact the same inner fields definitions

Comment: @Yuguang Which is exactly equivalent to only changing the name. You are certainly not changing wire type (it remains as submessage).